# Structuring an editor for HTML image maps

Tags: html, delphi, data-structures, delphi-7, imaging

**Summary:**

I'm beginning to build a tool for creating/editing HTML image maps, or 'hotspots' in a picture, using Delphi 7. The concept of the application is clear, and described below. I've done similar projects before, and I'm sure I can do this with whatever approach I take by myself. What I need help with is figuring out the best approach to how to store image maps in memory.

An image map may look like this:

```
<MAP NAME="someImageMap">
  <AREA SHAPE="RECT" COORDS="10,28,54,51" HREF="some_page.htm">
  <AREA SHAPE="RECT" COORDS="54,28,111,50" HREF="some_other_page.htm">
  <AREA SHAPE="RECT" COORDS="111,28,199,49" HREF="another_example.htm">
</MAP>
<IMG border=0 src="../images/SomeImage.png" width=571 height =451 
  isMap useMap=#someImageMap />
```

An `AREA` is a region within the image, given a shape and coordinates, to place an invisible hyperlink. They're also called `Hotspots`.

**Background**

I have a huge help file in HTML format which used to be in *HelpScribble* software, but now we're using *WinCHM*. HelpScribble had a tool called *SHGEditor* which did all this mapping for me. But WinCHM has no concept of image maps, and they're all over the code. So rather than trying to find a tool for this (which of course is the easy way out of this), I'm going to make one of my own.

**Image:**

[image: Beginnings of Editor]

**Issue:**

The confusion begins with deciding where to store the primary data for the `Hotspot` areas temporarily in memory...

- Directly in the HTML code?
- In a TList?
- In a TStringList?
- In an Array?
- In the TListView where I display a list of the hotspots?

That's the main question I'm asking.

Each I guess has its ups and downs. But the whole thing is thrown off when I think about the HTML editor. When modifications are done in either of the 3 edit tabs (either Image, HTML, or Hotspot List), it has to somehow synchronize those changes to the other two editors. So if a new hotspot is drawn on the image, of course I can put it to HTML no problem. But what about using the pure HTML code as the primary source? I'm going to be building/parsing it anyway, but I'm worried about performance with that. But then again, I can build a good back-end class to keep everything too. Which to consider the primary?

**Conclusion:**

So it all boils down to should I keep the primary data in the HTML source, the list view items, a custom list class (THotspots), or where?

Any tips, tricks, or suggestions are much appreciated.

**PS:**

I do in fact ask long questions quite often, sorry!

Comment: I have to ask, how are you planning to store the hotspot data ? I mean permanently - in a database, in some structured files ? I would personally prefer to store them into a database (there are lightweight solutions like for instance [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/index.html)), load them into the array of records (which you will display in some list component) and render them dynamically by building the HTML code (you can always prepare the frames behind the bounds, if you are planning to drag the maps). P.S. - sorry for my edit, it was accepted too late, I don't have enough reputation :)

Comment: No, no database or files (Although I'm contemplating making my own file format for this :D ) My original intention is to get HTML from the settings. But I'm making an editor as a larger project.

Comment: Building the HTML from the settings is the easy part, reading it is tricky but still very possible, but building an entire editor... Synchronization between each tab is going to be massive.

Comment: Now I see, what you mean. You want to choose a data type for storing the data which will be the best for synchronizing between `Map Image View`, `Map Design View`, `Map HTML Editor` and `Hotspot List`

Comment: I'm leaning towards keeping the original HTML source as the primary place, but I'm worried about performance...

Comment: I was writing the longer answer now, but maybe after this comment I got your situation. You have the data generated from another application. Anyway you will still render just the part of the map, so you'll have loaded just a small document in your web browser's cache, so there no need to worry about iterating through the elements (what is worse, if the `<area>`'s don't have the id attribute, your primary key are the coordinates). Iterate through the array (or TList; what's in the lowest level array of pointers) will be fast, so there's no problem.

Comment: The problem will be to build the list of all hotspots and their coordinates (including maps where they are placed) from the whole file.

Comment: Found a great HTML parser here: http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/htmlparser/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many reasons, I have decided to use the raw HTML as the base of the data. I was originally worried about performance using this approach, but since I found [this HTML parser component](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/htmlparser/index) for Delphi, performance isn't an issue. This parser can go through 50,000 tags in 1 second.

The core advantage of using the core HTML is the fact that I can maintain the HTML data in its original format. Any other method would most likely result in having to regenerate the HTML every time I need it, which would come in whatever format my app puts it in. But since I have this parser now, it's easy to simply change tag attributes with the wink of an eye.

Comment: Although I am considering the raw HTML as the primary data, I regardless still have to implement cross-editor translation. In other words, any time a change is made in one editor, those changes have to be distributed out to all the other editors too. So I have a function for each editor to each other editor. When a change is made in the HTML source, a `Synchronize` button becomes enabled, and upon clicking, parses the code and updates the image, record array, list view, etc.

Comment: Update: I have the editor coming along great! I had to pat myself on the back for this project, I'm surprised I've already gotten as far as I have. Performance is smooth, user friendliness is getting there, saving/loading my own INI file format for image maps is working too. Next steps are adding PNG support, copy/paste via menu and keyboard shortcuts, elliptical hotspots, and a side panel to browse a folder for HTML files to search for `<map>` tags, because after all, the whole purpose is because I already have 500+ pages with 100+ image maps...